# Git: cannot run git 'rm -rf . --cached'

Tags: ruby, git, git-rm

I'm working with Rubygems, and it's caching files in git a lot. The easy solution is just to run `git rm -rf . --cached`, but when I run it, this message appears:

```
fatal: pathspec '' did not match any files
```

Even if I run `git rm -rf ./\* --cached`, it still returns:

```
fatal: pathspec '*' did not match any files
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried passing the arguments in a sane order? (`git rm -rf --cached .`)

Comment: @NevikRehnel no, but it won't work either.

Comment: Ah, I'm pretty sure it's not the caching that's the issue.

Comment: What is your problem with changed files being staged, i.e., marked as possible parts of the next commit? You can mostly work by forgetting about the index/staged files by always either commiting with `-a` or giving explicit paths. The index is rarely needed, but essential when you do.

Comment: **Solved:** wasn't a caching error at all actually. No cached files existed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
git rm -r -f --cached -- .
```

(ie the path should be at the end)

But if `git status` mentions that no files have been added, then nothing 'cached' would be there to be removed.

> When `--cached` is given, the staged content has to match:
>
> - either the tip of the branch
> - or the file on disk,
>
> allowing the file to be removed from just the index.